# PHP mb_eregi_replace does not work

Tags: php, regex, utf-8

I am trying to match a whole UTF-8 word in PHP. This is how I am trying to do it:

```
<?php

    $string = 'DS DAMAT TAKIM ELBİSE (GOLD)';
    $search = 'takım elbise';
    $replace = 'TakımElbise';

    $result = mb_eregi_replace('/\b'.$search.'\b/ui', $replace, $string);
    echo $result;

    echo preg_match('/\b'.$search.'\b/ui', $replace);
?>
```

But it does not work. What can be the problem?

NOTE:
I have tried adding these lines at the beginning of script:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
```

No result.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry I have edited

Comment: I'm not sure what results you're trying to get, but try `echo preg_replace('/('.$search.')/iu', '$1', $replace);`

Comment: I just borrowed from an example on http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-eregi-replace.php being `echo preg_replace('/('.$f.')/iu', '<b>$1</b>', $s);`

Comment: What you were trying to do is just to find a match, instead of replacing it. Had you a conditional statement around your code, it may have worked.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry but you do not use $string at all, I wanted to replace it

Comment: I want to replace TAKIM ELBİSE with TakımElbise in $string

Comment: Ah ok. I see what you're trying to do. You want to find `takım` in `DS DAMAT TAKIM ELBİSE`, correct?

Comment: I want to find 'takım elbise' and replace it with 'TakımElbise'

Comment: I posted an answer below. It worked for me. If that is not satisfactory, let me know and I will delete my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't able to fully solve the problem, therefore I had to delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$string = 'DS DAMAT TAKIM ELBİSE (GOLD)';
//                           ^__ this isn't an I
$search = 'takım elbİse';
//                  ^__ this isn't an I
$replace = 'TakımElbise';

$result = preg_replace("/\b$search\b/ui", $replace, $string);
echo $result;
```

I've just change the `i` to `İ` in the search string. You may want to use lowercase (I haven't on my keyboard)

Comment: I am getting strings from webpages by scraping

Comment: @torayeff: Yes, but you have to change the search pattern, not the input string unless I miss something. How do you build the search pattern and the replace string?

Comment: the lowercase for "İ" must be "i". I guess the problem is with PHP mb_ functions. It seems that there is not a one-to-one correspondence between upper and lower case letters.

Answer (score 0):

See the comment here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php

Unlike `preg_replace`, `mb_ereg_replace` doesn't use separators

Example with `preg_replace`:

`$data = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9\.\-]/","",$data);`

Example with `mb_ereg_replace`:
`$data = mb_ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9\.\-]","",$data);`

Also, don't use the ui flags.